# Batch syntax issue. Not quoting or escaping correctly?

Tags: windows, batch-file

There's some syntax that I'm missing here. Running this batch file:

```
for /d %a in ("c:\Documents and Settings\*.*") do mkdir "%a\Application Data\vlc"
for /d %a in ("c:\Documents and Settings\*.*") do echo qt-privacy-ask=0 > "%a\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc"
```

And I get this output:

```
\Documents was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you got it, official reference: [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

> FOR command
>
> Use %variable to carry out for from
> the command prompt. Use %%variable to
> carry out the for command within a
> batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue... it seems like batch needs double %% for variables? Not sure but this worked:

```
for /d %%a in ("c:\Documents and Settings\*.*") do (
    mkdir "%%a\Application Data\vlc"
    echo qt-privacy-ask=0 > "%%a\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc" 
)
```